# In Javascript without jQuery, I am to find if any value in one array exists in a separate array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter

I am trying to determine if ANY value from one array matches ANY value from another array.  The problem that i am having is that if there are two values in my array and the first value is found but the second is not found, my indicator is coming up as FALSE when i need it to return TRUE.  Here is some example code that i'm working with:

```
var itemArray = ['apples','bananas','cherries'];
var categoryArray = ['donuts','cherries','eclairs','fruit','grapes'];

for(var z=0; z<itemArray.length; z++){
  for(var y=0; y<categoryArray.length; y++){
    if(itemArray[z] == categoryArray[y]) var isInArray = true;
    else var isInArray = false;
  }
}

alert(isInArray);
```

Appreciate the help, let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `break` or `return` once you've found a value that matches. Otherwise, the `else` case overwrites `isInArray` if it was already `true`. Alternately, initialize `isInArray` to `false`, and *only* assign it to `true` in the loop. Here's how I'd do it:

```
function isInArray(itemArray, categoryArray) {
    for(var z=0; z<itemArray.length; z++) {
      for(var y=0; y<categoryArray.length; y++) {
        if(itemArray[z] == categoryArray[y]) return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I prefer early return in cases such as this.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this was definitely helpful, i knew there was something small that i was missing.

Comment: When in doubt, you can always step through your code with a debugger to better understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simplify it a bit using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var itemArray = ['apples','bananas','cherries'];
var categoryArray = ['donuts','cherries','eclairs','fruit','grapes'];
var isInArray = false;
for(var z=0; z<itemArray.length; z++){
  if( categoryArray.indexOf(itemArray[z]) !== -1) {
    isInArray = true;
    break;
  }
}

alert(isInArray);
```